# Datepickers for departure and return dates

Tags: javascript, datetime, angular.js, twitter-bootstrap

I have to two datepickers. I want achieve the following functionality: the return date cannot be selected before the selected departure date and the departure date cannot be after the selected return date. Mainly I am interested in correctness of my angular architecture.

I have moved datepicker into my custom directive which I plan to reuse many times for different screen sizes.

Both datepickers reuse the same `DatepickerContoller` and I have one parent controller `FormDatepickerController` which shares information from both outbound and return datepickers.

Could you please review my code and let me know if my design is good enough?

**index.html**

```
<div ng-controller="FormDatepickerController as fd">
    <div ng-controller="DatePickerController as dp">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <date-picker date="fd.departDate" min-date="fd.departDate"></date-picker>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2">
            <date-picker date="fd.returnDate" min-date="fd.departDate"></date-picker>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**datepicker.html template**

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"
           datepicker-popup
           min-date="minDate"
           ng-model="date"
           is-open="isOpened"
           ng-required="true"
           close-text="Close" />
            <span ng-click="open($event)" class="btn btn-default input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>

</div>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module("fridayFly", ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

**datepicker-controller.js**

```
var app = angular.module("fridayFly");

(function(){

    function Controller($scope) {
        $scope.open = function($event) {
            $event.preventDefault();
            $event.stopPropagation();

            $scope.isOpened = true;
        };


        $scope.today = function() {
            $scope.dt = new Date();
        };
        $scope.today();

        $scope.clear = function () {
            $scope.dt = null;
        };

        $scope.toggleMin = function() {
            $scope.minDate = $scope.minDate ? null : new Date();
        };
        $scope.toggleMin();

        $scope.dateOptions = {
            formatYear: 'yyyy',
            startingDay: 1
        };

        $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
        $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];

    }

    app.controller('DatePickerController', Controller);


})();

(function(){

    function directive(){
        return {
            scope :{
                date:'=date',
                minDate:'=minDate',
                isOpened:'=isOpened'
            },
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'templates/datepicker/datepicker.html',
            controller: 'DatePickerController'
        };
    };

    app.directive('datePicker', directive);

})();
```

**form-datepicker-contoller.js**

```
var app = angular.module("fridayFly");


app.controller('FormDatepickerController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.toggleDepartDate = function() {
        $scope.departDate = $scope.departDate ? null : new Date();
    };
    $scope.toggleDepartDate();

    $scope.toggleReturnDate = function() {
        $scope.returnDate = $scope.returnDate ? null : new Date();
    };
    $scope.toggleReturnDate();

}]);
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some great answers!

Answer (score 1):

### Excess controllers?

This code appears to be similar to several examples of UI Bootstrap datepickers - e.g. [this plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/OVh5h7GJYkthVwCUkZwJ/). Initially the layout looked fine but then I realize that there are three total instances of `DatePickerController` - one for each `<date-picker>` plus the wrapping `<div ng-controller="DatePickerController as dp">`. My presumption is that you should be able to implement this without that wrapping `DatePickerController` but maybe there is something I am missing.

### Descriptive function/class names

I noticed that the functions for the controller and the directive are named `Controller` and `directive`, respectively. Most widely-accepted style guides call for class names in `UpperCamelCase` while method/function names should be in `lowerCamelCase` (e.g. the [Google Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#naming)). As your application grows it would be advisable to make the function names more descriptive - e.g. `datePickerController` and `datePickerDirective`.

### Functions only called once

Do the methods `toggleDepartDate()` and `toggleReturnDate()` in `FormDatepickerController` get called anywhere other than the controller initializer (i.e. immediately after they are declared)? If not, then the functionality within them could be moved outside the functions.

### IIFEs could be combined

There are two [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)s in **datepicker-controller.js**. Those could be combined into a single IIFE because there isn't any reason to have them separated (at least code-wise).